# Inner JOIN just last result

Tags: mysql

I just edit my old code and try to make nice complex query.

My query looks like:

```
SELECT axnmrs_cases.claimnumber as claim, axnmrs_cases.vin as vin, axnmrs_cases.date_created as date, axnmrs_calculations.totalcosts as totalcosts, axnmrs_cases.country as country
                    FROM axnmrs_cases
                    INNER JOIN axnmrs_calculations ON ( axnmrs_cases.case_id = axnmrs_calculations.case_id
                    AND axnmrs_cases.country = axnmrs_calculations.country ) 
                    WHERE vin = :vin
```

This works and display results, whats perfect (even I can't belieave it :D), however I need just last calculation not all of them.

```
                INNER JOIN axnmrs_calculations ON ( axnmrs_cases.case_id = axnmrs_calculations.case_id
                AND axnmrs_cases.country = axnmrs_calculations.country ) ORDER BY axnmrs_calculations.calculation_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

However I'm not sure how to limit just INNER JOIN not the whole query, can someone advise me please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get the last calculation per case_id?

Comment: Hey @Shadow, sorry I wasn't specifc, you are correct

Comment: I guess @Shadow is not correct since you have `ON ( axnmrs_cases.case_id = ...  AND axnmrs_cases.country)` . But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the last calculation per case_id and country, then you need to create a derived table (subquery in the from clause) that gets you these and you join the cases and calculations table on this derived table.

You need to have either an auto increment id in the calculations table or a timestamp, or a flag that identifies the last version of the calculations. I'll assume, that you have an autoincrement id field in the calculations table:

```
SELECT axnmrs_cases.claimnumber as claim, axnmrs_cases.vin as vin, axnmrs_cases.date_created as date, axnmrs_calculations.totalcosts as totalcosts, axnmrs_cases.country as country
FROM axnmrs_cases
INNER JOIN axnmrs_calculations AS ac ON ( axnmrs_cases.case_id = ac.case_id AND axnmrs_cases.country = ac.country )
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid, case_id, country FROM axnmrs_calculations GROUP BY case_id, country) AS T
ON ac.id=T.maxid and ac.case_idóT.case_id and ac.country=T.country
WHERE vin = :vin
```